# How to build libjingle_peerconnection of webrtc only

Tags: webrtc

I try to build the webrtc project. It is too big. The ninja file is generated for whole project. How could I just build a single libjingle_peerconnection lib  ?

Comment: [Check here](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/building_an_app)

Answer (score 1):

After running the hooks (ie. `gclient sync`) to setup the directories, you can compile the libs you want by running something like,

`ninja -C ./out <libjingle libs>`

You can also create your own separate .gyp file to build a static lib that has the libjingle libs as direct dependencies, that way you will just have to build that single lib that will link the libjingle libs.

Comment: I am not very familiar with gyp. The ninja seems generate by a python. Am I right? Do I need write python by myself to build a separate lib?

Comment: No, the ninja build script is generated by gyp. Using gyp is just one of the (relatively) easier option to create your own separate lib that hooks into WebRTC libs.

Comment: @ksb2go, do you know anything about building a shared libraries with that? Because I just went with bare `ar` and `ld` to avoid having anything in common with `ninja`, but it has inexplicably failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616318/undefined-reference-even-if-its-in-the-shared-library